# linux mint boot not reading my windows iso

Tags: linux-mint, boot

Hi I try linux mint cinnamon but not happy about using it so I try to change it again to windows 10 and I already get the ISO from windows and burn it with Disk Image writer but when I boot to install it linux not recognized it.I have 2 internal harddisk one for linux and 1 for windows iso but linux didnt read it when booting.I also use eksternal harddisk but it also didnt recognized it when booting to.As you can see at first picture both harddisk (eksternal or internal) already burned by the iso [image: windows iso already burn] . You can see the second picture none of harddisk read the windows iso,i feel linux prevent me for install windows 10 and it keep annoy me,any suggestion?

[image: windows iso not recognized when booting]

Comment: the harddisk condition is good,before burn the iso both harddisk save my file so harddisk failure can be removed

Comment: The second picture looks like the PC bios to me, which has nothing to do with Linux...

Comment: You need to make sure your bios/uefi has the cdrom or the other hard drive as a boot disk and make sure it is first in the list, check this example, for boot priority. https://www.groovypost.com/howto/bios-uefi-setup-guide-boot-from-cd-dvd-usb-drive-sd-card/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have cloned the iso file to a USB drive (there is a USB symbol in the screenshot of the file manager). Cloning works well with most Linux iso files, but it does not work with the current Windows iso files. You must use a dedicated tool for this purpose.

- In Linux Mint you can use the following tools to create a Windows installer in a USB drive.

  - [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) installed from its PPA can do a lot of other things too.
  - [WoeUSB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185) installed from its github page is a dedicated tool for this purpose.
- In Windows you can use the following tools to create a Windows installer in a USB drive.

  - Microsoft's own tool installed from Microsoft's web site is a dedicated tool for this purpose.
  - [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) can do a lot of other things too.